# Get signed split APKs by ABI

Tags: android, flutter, deployment, google-play, google-play-console

currently I can download the signed universal APK from Google Play Console but I can't seem to find a way to get signed apks for each ABI. I looked into Play Developer API but those just give APKs which are split to the bare bones and that creates another dilemma of having to merge them all but not being able to sign the merged APK with the App Signing Key(Managed by Google). Anyone here know of a way to get signed apks split by ABI?

The main idea of wanting ABI-split APKs is so it'll be a smaller APK when users who don't have access to Google Play Store download our app from our GitHub Releases page(or some equivalent site).